# Datawarehouse - Audit records.

Tags: sql, sql-server, pentaho, data-warehouse

I am working on a datawarehouse project that has around 7000 customers databases. I am extracting transactions and loading it in my fact tables. 
My source is highly transactional.If I start comparing every source customer data with the fact data,will take so much time. what is the best practice to compare the data. Also my source records does not contain any flag for deleted records. but the deleted transactions are valid for analysis.

How can I achieve both of them? Any suggestions would be helpful.I have never worked on any datawarehouse projects prior to this and I use pentaho for data Integration. Looking forward to hear some personal project experiences.

Comment: Dont really understand what is your question/problem and what you want to acommplish.

Comment: This question is too broad and opinion-based for Stack Overflow.   Please see if you can narrow the focus of it.

Comment: To make sure I get this, You are pulling from live data to create your fact table. So Your question trying to figure out to exclude records that are already in the fact table? As Tab mentioned that is a bit broad, the correct answer could any number of solutions. My guess would be an exclusion join would be the most performant, you can read more about theme here: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/23/how-to-write-a-sql-exclusion-join/

Comment: Need more information on the question.
You can look for option to implement CDC on the source, so that you can capture the changes and deal with it.
you can build trigger in source(not very eff)
do you want your dwh to be build intraday? why not overnight?